# Processing script cannot assign address on 224.0.0.1

Tags: macos, network

I'm trying to get a Processing script running on my MacBook that streams to a L3D Cube, [using this GitHub repo](https://github.com/amatelin/L3DCube-Processing-scripts). It's trying to assign a port for the stream but errors:

> opening socket failed: > address:224.0.0.1, port:2222 [group:null]

I've worked through making sure the address is in the routes table but it still doesn't work.

Trying ports 8080/8888 didn't work. Interestingly, it does work on my desktop running 10.13 but not on my laptop running 10.14. I am comparing the routing tables to see if I can figure out if the problem is there.

I'm not very well versed in network issues so any help would be appreciated.

```java
public class Streaming {
    public static L3D_UDP udp;  // define the UDP object
    boolean multicast;
    public static String address;
    private static int port=2222;

    //multicast constructor
    public Streaming()
    {
      multicast=true;
      address       = "224.0.0.1";  // this is the multicast IP -- the router reserves this address,
                                    //and forwards any packets it receives at this address to all hosts on the LAN
      udp = new L3D_UDP( this, port, address );
    }   

    public Streaming(int _port)
    {
      multicast=true;
      port=_port;
      address       = "224.0.0.1";  // this is the multicast IP -- the router reserves this address,
                                    //and forwards any packets it receives at this address to all hosts on the LAN
      udp = new L3D_UDP( this, port, address );
    }
```

<sup>Source:https://github.com/amatelin/L3DCube-Processing-scripts/blob/5dc9dfc19e2b0d0caec27bbe7fa2396eef8d2485/earth_weather_data/libraries/L3D/src/L3D/Streaming.java</sup>

Comment: The question title says "2224.0.0.1", the question just "224.0.0.1". Please use more care in asking questions. It's not just rude to expect people to do more work, but unlikely to get useful help. But, to take a stab in the dark: ports < 1000 require admin privileges. Try something > 1000?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Pardon my typo, I was not trying to be rude. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: for such use cases, why not go for ports which people use in web-testing.. 8080/ 8888 etc.  (ping me by @ankii)

Comment: Thanks ankii. Trying ports 8080/8888 didn't work. (Note: I also mistyped the port I was using, it was actually 2222. I really do need to take more care when posting questions!) Interestingly it does work on my desktop running 10.13 but not on my laptop running 10.14. I am comparing the routing tables to see if I can figure out if the problem is there.